# ASP .NET MVC 3 - RemoteAttribute override IsValid, access to the additional fields

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Folks, i am creating a new attribute which inhetirs from System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute. I would like to override the method IsValid for that the validation also works without the enabled JavaScript. But i don't know how i can acces to the additional fields. My code is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DocumentationAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute
{
    public DocumentationAttribute()
        : base("ValidPass", "Validation")
    {
        base.HttpMethod = "Post";
    }
    private DocumentationAttribute(string routeName)
        : base(routeName)
    {

    }
    private DocumentationAttribute(string action, string controller)
        : base(action, controller)
    {

    }
    private DocumentationAttribute(string action, string controller, string areaName)
        : base(action, controller, areaName)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //How can i access to the additional fields?
    }}
```

Class Model:

```
        [Display(Name = "Passport")]
        [Documentation(ErrorMessage = "{0} not valid", AdditionalFields = "IDPass")]
        public virtual String Passport
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do remote validation without javascript.  That's how it works.  You might as well just rely on server-side validation only, because that's the only kind of validation that works without javascript.

Are you trying to create a validator that works remotely with javascript, but does serverside if javascript is disabled?  If so, then you should create a custom attribute derived from ValidationAttribute, and use remote as well.

Specifically for your question, you need to create a public property in your attribute called AdditionalFields, this gets set in the initializer when you declare the property, then you can access the property from your IsValid.

EDIT:

Based on your additional information, you need to use the second form of IsValid that takes the validation context.  You would do something like this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var fields = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.AdditionalFields);
    var fieldsValue = (string)fields.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. I am newbie, so i don't know what it's the best option. My application must be accessible and i want to valid the id numbers of the users. I have in a library c# the functions for this validation. I would like to implemente both sort of validations: client or server. So, have i choosen the best option validating with remoteattribute? I don't understand what you mean about creating a custom attribute derived from ValidationAttribute and use remote as well... Are you so pleasant to send a sample code?

Comment: About remoteattribute, i have tried your solution, but i can only get the name of the field, but not the value. My model has an entity POCO with the metada and information and some SelectList objects. So i need to use a prefix in the action of the controller called for the remote validation.

I hope u can undestand me :) 

Thank you!

Comment: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidPass([Bind(Prefix = "Solicitud.DocIdentidad")] string DocIdentidad, [Bind(Prefix = "Solicitud.IdTipoDocIdentidad")] int? IdTipoDocIdentidad)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocIdentidad) || !IdTipoDocIdentidad.HasValue)
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
            return Json(Validaciones.IsValidoNIFNIE(DocIdentidad, (Enumerados.TipoDocumentacion)IdTipoDocIdentidad));
        }`