# ASP.MVC3 ModelState.IsValid not include RemoteAttribute checking

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I define a variable as

```
public class EditModel
{
    [Remote("IsNameAvailable", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Name is in use.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and in the Home controller

```
public JsonResult IsNameAvailable(string name)
{
    if (duplicate)
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    else
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but when I check the ModelState.IsValid in the Save action, it always return true even I can see the error message display on the View.

```
public ActionResult Save(EditModel editModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       //Return to view and display error in view
       return View("Home", editModel);
   }

   //Input data is valid and save record
   Repository.Save(editModel.Name);
}
```

How can the ModelState check also the Validation rules by RemoteAttribure in a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options. You can implement either the IDataErrorInfo or IValidatableObject interface and redo the validation there. These interfaces are supported out-of-the-box by MVC and your ModelState will reflect this.

Your other option is creating your own attribute that derives from RemoteAttribute. In this custom attribute, add logic for applying the same validation server-side.

The last option is the one I would go for, but that does take up a bit more time. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240436/asp-net-mvc-3-remoteattribute-override-isvalid-access-to-the-additional-fiel) should help you with it though.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! The case is that I have many models like that and I want to find the best option to reduce the code. The first and second options need to code depends on the number of model which using the remote attribute. Can you explain more of the last option?

Comment: The RemoteAttribute's IsValid method actually does get called serverside. If you look at this method with a .NET decompiler, you'll see that all this method does is "return true;". Create your own attribute that derives from RemoteAttribute and place some actual validation logic in that IsValid() method. For example, you could create an extra property on your own attribute, say ValidationMethod. When using the attribute, you can then pass along  the method that should perform the validation. And in your IsValid() method, you can call that validation method.